# custom controllerfactory: httpcontext.current.user and httpcontext.current.session are null only on ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, post

I've implemented a custom controller factory in ASP MVC3 with autofac to achieve a very basic plugin management by deriving from DefaultControllerFactory.

In the overrided GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) method I do some checks with a session variable or httpcontext.current.user to determine which controller type I must provide to an end user.

The point is that if I do a normal GET (or by using a childaction inside a view) I have those two set when GetControllerType is called but if I do a POST ajax call (with contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8') via jquery, directly to the actionmethod, the user and the session are null in my httpcontext but they are set an instant later, when I try to access them in my controller action (or in an actionfilter).

Also the AcquireRequestState in this case is never fired and if I navigate through RequestContext property I can see that cookies for session (with session id) are valid.

Do you have any hint?? And why on normal GET calls session and user are set at that time and I dont have this problem?

The code is like this:

```
protected override Type GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
{
    if(plugins.All.Where(w=> w.Name == HttpContext.Current.Session["pluginName"].ToString() && w.User == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) 
        [do stuff]
}
```

I can avoid Session but I cannot avoid matching for the current user.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  did you ever find a fix?